# Where are Rails helpers available?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm referring to the modules you create in `app/helpers`. Are they available in:

- Views?
- Controllers?
- Models?
- Tests?
- Other files?
- Sometimes?
- All the time?

Comment: The first chunk answers your question I believe, http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html

Comment: The docs don't mention anything other than views and controllers. Also, I'm new to Ruby/Rails and I didn't understand what it meant about being accessible only through `#helpers`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Rails 5 all Helpers are available to all Views and all Controllers, and to nothing else.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html

> These helpers are available to all templates by default.
>
> By default, each controller will include all helpers.

In Views you can access helpers directly:

```
module UserHelper
  def fullname(user)
    ...
  end
end

# app/views/items/show.html.erb
...
User: <%= fullname(@user) %>
...
```

In Controllers you need the `#helpers` method to access them:

```
# app/controllers/items_controller.rb
class ItemsController
  def show
    ...
    @user_fullname = helpers.fullname(@user)
    ...
  end
end
```

You can still make use of helper modules in other classes by `include`ing them.

```
# some/other/klass.rb
class Klass
  include UserHelper
end
```

The old behavior was that all helpers were included in all views and just each helper was included in the matching controller, eg. `UserHelper` would only be included in `UserController`.

To return to this behavior you can set `config.action_controller.include_all_helpers = false` in your `config/application.rb` file.

Comment: One major gotcha when including helpers in other kinds of classes like Presenters/Decorators is that most of the view helpers rely on the view context. You need to get the view context either from the view (self) or by calling `view_context` from the controller and passing it as a constructor dependency or an argument.