# rails how to use helpers with ERB.new in service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I have a service that uses an ERB file to render a template form.

In the form I use several helpers, but they don't seem to be available in this context.

how could I use my helpers in the rendering via `ERB.new(template).result(binding)` ?

this is the error I'm getting:

```
*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `image_encoded' for #<MyService>
```

here's the call in the service `app/services/my_service.rb` file:

`ERB.new(template).result(binding)`

here's my helper `app/helpers/my_helper.rb`:

```
module MyHelper
  def image_encoded(image_url)
    <<image stuff>>
  end
end
```

here's my call to the helper in the `app/views/my_template/my_template.html.erb` file:

```
<img src="<%= image_encoded(image) %>"/>
```

Comment: What is the location of your helperfile? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43431955/where-are-rails-helpers-available states if it's located in `app/helpers/` then methods there will be available in the view

Comment: the helperfile is in `app/helpers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your service your helpers are not included by default. You can include the methods from a particular helper like this:

```rb
class MyService
  include MyHelper
end
```